# Why getting an exception in spring mvc application with spring boot actuator when add @EnableAutoConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a spring mvc application where I am trying to add spring boot actuator for performance metrics. I am getting an exception when running it into tomcat server. Can anyone please help me how can I use spring boot actuator 2.4.2 into spring 5.2.8 for getting the performance metrics?
Spring version : 5.2.8.RELEASE
Spring Boot actuator version : 2.4.2

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Import(EndpointAutoConfiguration.class)
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class DemoActuatorConfig{
    
}
```

Exception :

```
Feb 11, 2021 9:05:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: Servlet.init() for servlet [spring] threw exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.springmvc.actuator.demo2.DemoActuatorConfig]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.getApplicationStartup()Lorg/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup;
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.access$800(ConfigurationClassParser.java:110)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:811)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:808)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:779)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:192)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:319)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:533)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:591)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1089)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4876)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5185)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3763)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:5535)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1353)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1357)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1357)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1335)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.getApplicationStartup()Lorg/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup;
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.startup.StartupEndpointAutoConfiguration$ApplicationStartupCondition.getMatchOutcome(StartupEndpointAutoConfiguration.java:63)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:225)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:599)
    ... 39 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Spring Boot 2.4.x with Spring Framework 5.2.x. You are using Spring Boot 2.4.2 which, [as noted in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.2/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-system-requirements), requires Spring Framework 5.3.3 or above.